# Connecting to MS Access Database within ASP (an architecture mismatch)

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

Ok, I have searched and read other posts and other areas from Google but still am struggling.

I have created a small ASP page which loads and functions as planned. I've created a small MS Access Database in MC Access (2003 - 32bit) and later I had another go with MS Access (2010 - 32 Bit)
When I've added a connection string into my ASP Page I get:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an
>   architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
>   /default2.asp, line 3

I researched this error and found I was trying to use the 64 drivers, I have since used the 32 bit drivers by going to SysWOW64 folder and using the ODBC Administrator there. but I still seem to be getting that error message.

As for the particular string I have used, I have tried all of these (changing the reflect my database name and location) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300382

When I have tried with these different strings, some of the messages were different but still no connection.

Also, when trying to create a DSN, I wasn't sure which driver to select, there were several for MS Access all slightly different names. To sontinue with my scatter-gun approach, I have tried them all.

I figure I have overlooked something very simple, but at a loss. Can anyone point me in the right direction (checks that I can do) I'm a complete novice in this subject but hope to have a simple set-up at home so I can stop breaking the work's system ;-)

My operating system is Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: [This is an interesting article](http://www.altova.com/Access-Database-OLEDB-32bit-64bit.html), but I'm not sure how old it is (though it's at least from 2010).  You may find the links help you out a lot.

Comment: It may be worth trying a DNS-less connection instead of using a DSN.

Comment: Hi John, I have tried DSN-less as well ... I tried file DSN as well .... I'm doing something fundamentally wrong ... just can't find what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, The link Westie left, lead me to another avenue and after some more searches via Google I found this [Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/1c63e3ae-e001-4066-9eac-ad9162116603)

It basically describes how to ensure my IIS was using the 32bit drivers, which it wasn't. I used the first option mentioned and now everything works.

Cheers for all your help.
Leon